# Do the linear transformation is the only transformation that invariant under change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function), there are linear transformation, affine transformation and so on.

It also mentions about translation, reflection, rotation, etc. I know which transformation is a linear or affine transformation. I think that the affine transformation is more general, I am not sure that the linear transformation is a specific case of the affine transformation (Kabo already answered this).

I just learn about the linear transformation as (1,1)tensor.

I understand that -form (one-form, bilinear and so on) can be viewed as linear transformation $V\times V\times...\rightarrow R$.

**In conclusion, I know that linear transformation is invariant under change of basis and affine may or may not but I don't know that is there any other type of transformation that invariant under change of basis.**

The other question is about the affine transformation.

Is the linear transformation is a subset of the affine transformation?

Comment: Every linear transformation is affine.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean by invariant under a change of basis? Do your transformations map vector spaces to vector spaces?